Difficulty setting up interface. Unity c#
I am setting up and interface and when trying to assign it so it ca be used, It returns error "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'ITower'". When searching online for solutions, all have to do with the abstract part of the error and not the interface part.
Interface code:
public interface ITower
{
    void SetToPlaced();

}

My attempt at assigning the interface:
ITower towerInterface = new ITower();

The interface and the line currently erroring are on one script, "BuildManager" and the SetToPlaced() method is on another script, "DropperScript" I am instantiating a dropper prefab a through the BuildManager. I have tried doing ITower towerInterface = tower where tower is the instantiated prefab but that errored as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface#example-interface

I am using a interface because the code I need to run is shared between many scripts with different names, so I can't do "ITower towerInterface = new 'ScriptName'();" I also tried using 'MonoScript but that didn't work either

This seems to be an XY problem, please explain in detail what you really want to do.

You can't dump a few lines of code totally out of context and expect people to help. Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

You cannot create an interface. You must implement the interface on a class or struct to be able to create an object that can be assigned to a reference to the interface.
public interface ITower
{
    void SetToPlaced();

}

public class Tower : ITower
{
    public void SetToPlaced()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

ITower towerInterface = new Tower();


I should have gave more information. The interface and the line currently erroring are on  one script, "BuildManager" and the SetToPlaced() medthod is on another script, "DropperScript" I am instantiating a dropper prefab a through the BuildManager. I have tried doing "ITower towerInterface = tower" where "tower" is the instantiated prefab but that errored as well.

It would seem that you're trying to get the script on a GameObject that implements the ITower interface. On that assumption, what you want to do is find the script that has the specific class like this:
var towerInterface = tower.GetComponent<ITower>();

Or, the safer way:
if (!tower.TryGetComponent<ITower>( out var towerInterface ) )
{
  Debug.LogError ( $"Could not find ITower on this GameObject '{name}'." );
}
// Proceed with towerInterface ...

The above code assumes that tower has already instantiated from a prefab. This will simply look for any script on the GameObject that "is a" ITower.
